# How I merge results of two queries

Tags: sql, select

**Here are the queries and there op, how do i merge those queries ans get required result**

1.

```
SELECT sum(rpl) AS rpl,decrip 
from COMM c, BOOK b
   WHERE b.bookid=c.parbookid and booktype='trading' 
   GROUP BY b.decrip
```

O/P

```
RPL DECRIP 
55  RBC 
45  bny
```

2.

```
SELECT sum(estcomm) as commission,decrip 
from COMM c, BOOK b 
    WHERE b.bookid=c.parbookid and booktype='wash' 
    GROUP BY b.decrip
```

O/P

```
COMMISSION DECRIP 
2234       RBC 
2468       bny
```

How do i get output

```
 
RPL COMMISSION DECRIP 
55  2234       RBC 
45  2468       bny
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```
SELECT sum(rpl) AS rpl, sum(estcomm) as commission,decrip 
from COMM c, BOOK b
   WHERE b.bookid=c.parbookid 
        and (booktype='trading' OR  booktype='wash)
   GROUP BY b.decrip
```

Comment: I want specific column when booktype is wash and a different column when booktype is trading. It can not be used in same slect statement.

Comment: Question is depicting different from that in output. I think what you are asking is possible by using `case when` statement. Please explain a little what column are required for what condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (assuming that `booktype` is a column under `BOOK` table)

```
SELECT sum(c.rpl) AS rpl,sum(c.estcomm) as commission,b.decrip 
from COMM c
join BOOK b
on b.bookid=c.parbookid 
where b.booktype in('trading','wash') 
GROUP BY b.decrip
```